# jqtransform Drop down loses CSS properties when I add multiple attribute to the Select input

Tags: jquery

I am working with a search form that using the jqTransform jquery plugin. Its working fine with all other type of inputs like text box,select, check box . But in the case of multiple select box it not working ,had lost all the css properties.

Code I've used given below

```
<select name='type' multiple>
<option value="">Any</option>
<option value="1">Tiger</option>
<option value="2">Parrot</option>
<option value="3">Cat</option>
<option value="3">Dog</option>
<option value="3">Rabbit</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqtransform doesn't support multiple select